# 'nz-alert' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

'nz-alert' is not a known element:

1. If 'nz-alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nz-alert' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibs6E.png)

I just opened an Angular project using VSCode, and after loading the dependencies, the project runs successfully without any errors. However, I am getting error prompts in the editor. How should I handle this situation?

Some of the online solutions I found did not work after trying them. I know it's not a code issue; it's likely a configuration problem with VSCode regarding Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to import `nzAlertModule` wherever your component is declared, either in its declared module imports or if its standalone, then inside the component decorator imports array.

```
import { NzAlertModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/alert';
```

[documentation nzAlert](https://ng.ant.design/components/alert/en)